Select any 4 numbers, erase them, and replace them with the cube root of the sum of their cubes. Whats the largest possible sum? [STEMS by CMI]

The numbers $1, 2, \dots , 100$ are written on a board. Every minute, Sheldon selects four
numbers $a, b, c, d$ on the board, erases them, and then writes ($a^3 + b^3 + c^3 + d^3)^\frac{1}{3}$
in their place.
He continues to do that until no more numbers can be erased. Let the largest number remaining on the board be $N$. What is $N^3$?

This is problem number 2 asked in the 2024 STEMS CMI exam. The maximum $N$ would be the sum of cubes from $1$ to $100$. Since there's no answer key, could someone please verify if I am thinking correctly?

We can simplify the problem.
We have 100 numbers written on a board : $1^3, 2^3, 3^3, 100^3$
At each step, we select 4 numbers, we erase them from the board, and we add their sum.
The sum of all numbers on the board never change.
At the beginning, we have 100 numbers.
After the $1$st step, we have $97$ numbers, then $94$ numbers ... and after $33$ steps, we have only $1$ number. (it is important)
This number is the sum $1^3+2^3+ ...+100^3$.
Your result is correct.

I see, thanks! So the answer is $5050^6$?

@Kraken How did you get that? It seems very large. EG $5050^6 > 1000^6 = 10^{18} > 100 \times 100^3$.

@Kraken $$\sum_{k=1}^{n} k^3 = \left( ~\frac{n(n+1)}{2} ~\right)^2.$$  When $~n = 100,~$ you get $~(5050)^2.$

Actually, the question asks for $N^3$, and I think $N = 5050^2$? or is it $N = 5050^\frac{2}{3}$?

$N^3$ is already $1^3+2^3+... +100^3$ ; no need to raise this number to his cube.

@Kraken I agree with the answer of Lourrran, which I regard as elegant.  I advise you to take a piece of scratch paper, and work through the alternate problem of initially having the numbers $~{1,2,\cdots,8}~$ written on the board.  At each step, simply choose any $~4~$ of the numbers, and work through to the end.  This will expand your intuition and make it easier for you to understand Lourrran's answer.

@Kraken In Lourrran's answer, which focuses on the original problem of starting with $~{ ~1, ~2, ~\cdots,  ~100 ~},~$ there may be a point of confusion.  His analysis demonstrates that in the math problem specified in your posted question, the final number will actually be $$\left[ ~1^3 + 2^3 + 3^3 + \cdots + 100^3 ~\right]^{1/3} = (5050)^{2/3}.$$

Okay okay got it
